# Can't do anything in Central Administration or Site collection features

Tags: 2013

How can I resolve this problem? It doesn't let me create a new site collection or activate sharepoint publishing feature in site collection feature.

> The group name is empty, or you are using one or more of the following
>   invalid characters: " / \ [ ] : | < > + = ; , ? * ' @

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with some language packs I believe - are you using something other than the default English version?

If so then that error can occur.  If you create it with English first that may help?

Comment: Now I'm intalling english language package for sharepoint server. I will write again, if something happens or it works.

Comment: It didn't work. I will try to update the server.